# UIImageView which is subview of UICollectionCell will hide when Interactive transition

Tags: ios, swift

[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdVSQ.gif)

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGnJ3.png)

I implemented a UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, when  Interactive transition , some UIImageView will not show.

Comment: MoveableTransitionAnimator.swift   https://gist.github.com/3ead284198338856fa69e7d2e634bf5f        PinterestLayout    https://gist.github.com/87213f8d38414d64c74e80862587abd7

Comment: Is there any implementation on viewWillAppear or viewDidApper methods? If so, please add it. Also, add viewDidLoad code.

Comment: I don't hide this UIimageView ,when this image is not show,hidden is false.view by reveal,    http://7xq04a.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/reveal.jpg